# Recovering files from IIS system (inetsrv) directory?

Tags: iis

Some file from my inetsrv directory (c:\windows\system32\inetsrv) were accidentally removed. Is there a way to get them back? Reinstalling IIS server role doesn't help, because windows doesn't remove inetsrv directory when removing the role.

Answer (score 0):

Option A: From the Control Panel, click on "Add Remove Programs" > "Add/Remove Windows Components" unselect the IIS component to uninstall and reinstall the same by selecting the IIS component.

Option B: Try copying the files from another machine that has IIS installed.

Comment: Option A is the same thing I've tried, as on Windows Server IIS is installed and uninstalled by adding and removing Web server role. So it seems like B is the only option. I just hoped there was some "legal" way of recovering this folder.

Comment: Copying files from another Server 2008 machine didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the system was the only way to recover IIS.